# (DOM issue) not returning anything

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm new to JavaScript and I was trying to manipulate the value of an HTML `h2` element with the class of "text" when the users clicks on the button with the id `"push"` and change it to the value of the input `class="inputV"`, however i noticed that when there's no value in the input field the whole block just disappears so I tried to return a different value if the input is not true! so how do i go out about doing this! that's what I've tried so far.

```
    function input(){
    var inputValue= document.getElementById('inputV').value;
    var text = document.querySelector('.text').textContent;

    if (inputValue){
            text = inputValue;
            }else{
                text = 'Null';
        }
        return text;
    };

    document.getElementById('push').addEventListener('click',input);



    <div class=container><h1>JavaScript OOP</h1>
            <div>
                <form class="input">
                    <input id="inputV" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div><h2 class="text">Results</h2></div>
            <button id="push" value="Sign me in" onclick="input()">Sign me in</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: please add your HTML CSS too. and create a code snippet to get a batter help.

Comment: The code you've provided does actually nothing in any case. `addEventListener` doesn't use the return value of the handler function anywhere (or the inline listener, which showed up after your edit), and the handler does not use the variables either.

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set `onclick="input()"` for the button you don't need to extra define an event listener. Also you can make the function body a bit shorter

```js
function input(){
    var inputValue= document.getElementById('inputV').value;
    var text = document.querySelector('.text');
    
    text.textContent = inputValue || 'Null';
};

// document.getElementById('push').addEventListener('click',input);
```

```html
<div class=container><h1 class="text">JavaScript OOP</h1>
      <div>
       <form class="input">
        <input id="inputV" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name">
       </form>
      </div>
      <div><h2 class="text">Results</h2></div>
      <button id="push" value="Sign me in" onclick="input()">Sign me in</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialization of `text` is not needed, just declare it.
Replace your `return text` with assignment to `<h2>`as below

```
function input(){
    var inputValue= document.getElementById('inputV').value;
    //var text = document.querySelector('.text').textContent;
    var text;

    if (inputValue){
        text = inputValue;
    }
    else{
        text = 'Null';
    }
    // return text;
    document.querySelector('.text').textContent = text;
}

document.getElementById('push').addEventListener('click',input);
```